# Traverse a big table in PostgreSQL with Propel

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, propel

I recently had a task to iterate over a big table (~40KK records) in PostgreSQL using Propel and encountered performance issues, both memory limit and execution speed. My script had been running for 22(!) hours.

The task was to retrieve records based on some criteria (not active for the last 6 months) and archive them (move to another table) and all related entities from other tables.

The primary table, my script is working on, has several columns: `id`, `device_id`, `application_id`, `last_activity_date` and others, that don’t have any significant meaning here. This table contains information about applications installed on device and their last activity dates. There may be several records with the same `device_id` and different `application_id`. Here is a sample from the table:

```
     id    | device_id | application_id |   last_init_date
 ----------+-----------+----------------+---------------------
         1 |         1 |              1 | 2013-09-24 17:09:01
         2 |         1 |              2 | 2013-09-19 20:36:23
         3 |         1 |              3 | 2014-02-11 00:00:00
         4 |         2 |              4 | 2013-09-29 20:12:54
         5 |         3 |              5 | 2013-08-31 19:41:05
```

So, the device is considered to be old enough to be archived, if the maximum `last_activity_date` for the particular `device_id` in this table is older than 6 months. Here is the query:

```
SELECT device_id
FROM device_applications
GROUP BY device_id
HAVING MAX(last_init_date) < '2014-06-16 08:00:00'
```

In Propel it looks like:

```
\DeviceApplicationsQuery::create()
  ->select('DeviceId')
  ->groupByDeviceId()
  ->having('MAX(device_applications.LAST_INIT_DATE) < ?', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
  ->find();
```

The resulting set, as you understand, is too big to fit in memory, so I have to split it somehow into chunks.

The question is: what is the best strategy to choose in this situation to decrease memory consumption and to speed up the script?
In my answer I'll show you what I've found so far.

Comment: Why can't you move all records with just one query to the archives? 40k records isn't that much.

Comment: 40KK, it is 40 millions

Comment: 40 million records is a lot more, but could be fast when your hardware can handle this amount of data. Did you check an common table expression including the DELETE and INSERT in a single query? ORM (any type of ORM) and performance is always a challenge, ORM's aren't made for it.

Comment: Yes, I understand that ORM in general are not suitable for such cases, but the problem is the main entity (device) has a lot of related entities (5 other tables actually, with foreign key constraints) that have to be archived too. And the logic of archiving related records is implemented in ORM classes.

Comment: This is what I did and I pointed it out in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know three strategies of traversing a big table.

#### 1. Good old limit/offset

The problem with this approach is that the database actually examines the records, that you want to skip with `OFFSET`. Here is a quote from the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-limit.html):

> The rows skipped by an OFFSET clause still have to be computed inside the server; therefore a large > OFFSET might be inefficient.

Here is a simple example (not my initial query):

```
explain (analyze)
SELECT *
FROM device_applications
ORDER BY device_id
LIMIT 100
OFFSET 300;
```

Execution plan:

```
Limit  (cost=37.93..50.57 rows=100 width=264) (actual time=0.630..0.835 rows=100 loops=1)
    ->  Index Scan using device_applications_device_id_application_id_unique on device_applications  (cost=0.00..5315569.97 rows=42043256 width=264) (actual time=0.036..0.806 rows=400 loops=1)
Total runtime: 0.873 ms
```

Pay special attention to the actual results in **Index scan** section. It shows, that PostgreSQL worked with **400** records, which is offset (300) plus limit (100). So this approach is quite inefficient, especially taking into consideration the complexity of the initial query.

#### 2. Ranging by some column

We can avoid the limitations of the limit/offset approach by making the query work with ranges of the table, which are made by slicing the table by a column.

To clarify, let’s imaging you have a table with 100 records, you can divide this table into five ranges by 20 records in each: 0 - 20, 20 - 40, 40 - 60, 60 - 80, 80 - 100, and then work with the smaller subsets. In my case the column we can range by is `device_id`. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT device_id
FROM device_applications
WHERE device_id >= 1 AND device_id < 1000
GROUP BY device_id
HAVING MAX(last_init_date) < '2014-06-16 08:00:00';
```

It groups records by `device_id`, extracts the range and applies the condition on `last_init_date`. Of course, it may be (and will be in most cases) that there will be no records matching the condition. So, the problem with this approach is that you have to scan the whole table, even if the records you want to find are just 5% of all the records.

#### 3. Using cursors

What we need is a [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29). Cursors allow to iterate over the result set without fetch the whole data at once. In PHP you make use of cursors when you iterate over a [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php). A simple example:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
$stmt->execute();

// Iterate over statement using a cursor
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // Do something
}
```

In Propel you can make use of this PDO's feature with a `PropelOnDemandFormatter` class. So, the final code:

```
$devApps = \DeviceApplicationsQuery::create()
  ->setFormatter('\PropelOnDemandFormatter')
  ->select('DeviceId')
  ->groupByDeviceId()
  ->having('MAX(device_applications.LAST_INIT_DATE) < ?', $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
  ->find();

/** @var \DeviceApplications $devApp */
foreach ($devApps as $devApp) {
    // Do something
}
```

Here the call to `find()` will not fetch the data, but instead will create a collection with on demand object creation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ended up using ->setFormatter(ModelCriteria::FORMAT_ON_DEMAND) (http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html)

Comment: 1. I wouldn't recommend using OFFSET. 2. The slicing thing can work only if you have all the records intact in the DB. usually not. It is better if you save the last ID that was processed and in the next iteration you use it as the starting point. In this case you have to use LIMIT but without OFFSET.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP and do not need results to be hydrated to PHP entities (objects) you may use PommProject/Foundation package. The script will simply be something like

```
<?php

$loader = require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$pomm = new PommProject\Foundation\Pomm(
    [
    'project_name' => ['dsn' => 'pgsql://user:pass@host:port/db_name']
    ]
);
$sql = <<<SQL
with
    removed as (delete from a_table where val1 = $* and … returning *)
insert into another_table select * from removed
SQL;

$pomm['your_project']
    ->getQueryManager()
    ->query($sql, [$value1, …]);
```

Be sure the indexes are properly set for your delete query and it should be a way faster.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I did not know about the Pomm project.